# Create const char* using ints

Tags: c++, string, printf

whats the best way of creating a 'const char*' using available variables? For example, a function requires a const char* as a parameter to locate a file i.e. "invader1.png". If I have 5 different invader images, how can I iterate from 1:5 so "Invader1.png".."Invader2.png..etc etc
so i want "invader" + %d + ".png"

i tried sprintf and casting but to no avail.

I hope my description makes sense, thanks

update with code:

```
 for (int y=0; y<250; y+=50){
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "invader" << (y/50) << ".png";
            const char* rr = ss.str().c_str();
            printf("%s", rr);
            for (int x=0; x<550;x+=50){
                Invader inv(rr, x+50, y+550, 15, 15, 1, false, (y/50 + 50));
                invaders[i] = inv;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should really show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::stringstream`. Something like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "invader" << my_int << ".png";
my_func(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but im still having problems. When debugging it says rr's value is "0x0040f6a8", and my wogl based program wont run. Heres my code:

Comment: Don't forget about [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: I dont know how to use code tags in replies, so I put it in OP

Comment: @Milk Your Invader object has to copy the c string as it's getting invalidated.

Comment: Pubby, sorry but can you clarify what you mean by that? thanks I appreciate your help

Comment: @Milk What the pointer is pointing to only exists until the end of the iteration.

Comment: But with each iteration of y, isnt rr redefined as the next picture? i.e. first its invader0.png, then after the x iterations it's redefined as invader1.png

Comment: @Milk The pointer is, but what it points to isn't. I can't really debug your code for you, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, you can simply use `std::string` and then use the `c_str()` function to get a `const char*` which you can pass to the function. One simple way to construct such strings is to use `std::ostringstream` from `<sstream>`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "invader" << i << ".png";
    foo(ss.str().c_str()); // where foo is the specified function
}
```

You could also use sprintf() and a character array, but then you need to pay attention to things like the size of the buffer. For the sake of completeness, here's how to do the same with sprintf, but I suggest you go with the `std::string` approach, which is more C++-like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    char buf[13]; // big enough to hold the wanted string
    std::ostringstream ss;
    sprintf(buf, "invader%d.png", i);
    foo(buf); // where foo is the specified function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then i would guess your looking to cast an `int` variable to `char`, so you can iterate through your invader%d.png files.

Have you tried `itoa` function ?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/